# Terraform apply hangs with no output

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Running Terraform with version 0.11.13, hangs when trying to run `terraform apply`. It doesn't show any output even after hours. I am using AWS as provider.

```
Terraform v0.11.13
+ provider.aws v2.10.0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just figured that the AWS Session was timed out. Had to renew the session and generate the new security token.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you can debug Terraform by setting the [TF_LOG environment variable.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_log)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in CI or GitHub Actions and this happens, be sure to auto approve the prompt when calling apply.

```
terraform apply -auto-approve
```